# .Net MAUI: AppxManifest.xml missing

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, maui, maui-windows

In a .Net MAUI application, I would like to get the current position of the device. The code looks like it works (tested in another environment), but during the building I get the following error message:

Could not find file 'C:***********\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\ win10-x64\AppxManifest.xml'

The file is really missing, it is not created during the build. How to force Visual Studio 2022 to create it?

Environment: Windows 10, .Net 6.0, VS2022

Thank you in advance for your help!

I created the file manually, the build is ok, but this is not a solution for a longer time

Comment: could you pls take a try with [this workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9064#issuecomment-1685883983)?

Comment: Upgrade your .NET 6 to .NET 7 (and as soon as possible to .NET 8)

Comment: @TinyWang: The workaround works, thanks! :) I modified the csproj, to automatically copy the missing file to the right place

Comment: Thanks for your reply and pls allow me to add that workaround below to end this question : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a similar issue in github and thanks for the [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9064#issuecomment-1685883983) shared by @wulf11 which is confirmed by OP that he modified the csproj, to automatically copy the missing file to the right place.

In the workaround, it still requires to create the folder MsixContent
and insert the AppxManifest.xml manually after `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish`.